# Aws sdk for .NET custom region endpoint configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to configure aws sdk for .net for using cloud service provider which provides aws compatible api. The code below for uploading using aws sdk for php works, but how to configure it properly for aws sdk .net, especially regions part:
This code works in php:

```
    $bucketName = 'big_bucket';
    $filePath = './img33.png';
    $keyName = basename($filePath);
    $IAM_KEY = 'top_secret_key';
    $IAM_SECRET = 'top_secret_secret';
    
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
    
    // Set Amazon S3 Credentials
    $s3 = S3Client::factory(
        array(
            'endpoint' => 'https://s3-kna1.citycloud.com:8080',
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => $IAM_KEY,
                'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
            ),
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 's3-kna1',
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => true
        )
    );
            $s3->putObject(
                array(
                    'Bucket'=>$bucketName,
                    'Key' =>  $keyName,
                    'SourceFile' => $keyName,
                    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
                    'ACL' => 'public-read'
                )
            );
```

The code below for .net does not work yet:

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
    
    public class CityCloudFileHandler
    {
        private string _accessKey;
        private string _secretKey;
        private string _mediaBucket;
        private string _serviceUrl;
        private S3CannedACL _s3CannedAcl;
        private AmazonS3Config _s3Config;

        public CityCloudFileHandler(string accessKey, string secretKey, string mediaBucket, string serviceUrl,
            S3CannedACL s3CannedAcl = null)
        {
            _accessKey = accessKey;
            _secretKey = secretKey;
            _mediaBucket = mediaBucket;
            _serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
            _s3CannedAcl = s3CannedAcl;
            _s3Config = new AmazonS3Config
            {
                ServiceURL = "https://s3-kna1.citycloud.com:8080",
                ForcePathStyle = true
            };
        }
        
        private IAmazonS3 MediaS3()
        {
            return new AmazonS3Client(_accessKey, _secretKey, _s3Config);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the constructors for the AmazonS3Client accept a RegionEndpoint example. The value looks like this:

RegionEndpoint.USWest2 or RegionEndpoint.USEast1

Here is a link to the AmazonS3Client API documentation: [AmazonS3Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=S3/MS3ListBuckets.html)

In addition, if you have setup a default user using the AWS CLI by creating two files (stored in: C:\Users\USER_NAME.aws\ on Windows)

The file credentials should contain the following information:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = your_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key = your_secret_access_key
```

and a second file named config will contain (at least) the following lines:

```
[default]
region = us-east-2
```

Once that user has been setup, you can call the client constructor without parameters as long as the bucket is in the same region as the default user.

There is an example for uploading objects to an S3 bucket here: [UploadObjectExample](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/dotnetv3/S3/UploadObjectExample)